# Immutable pattern requirments

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am studying Immutable pattern using java , but i can't understand the following two requirements :

1. Instance methods which access properties must not change instance variables
2. Ensure that the constructor of the immutable class is the only place where the values of instance variables are set or modified.

Please someone give a simple example for the first point. For the second point, i can't understand how we can modify the variables through the constructor while they are final?

Comment: Point (1) just means "don't have setters".  Because if you have setters (or anything else that changes an object's state), your object is not immutable.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem how do you will have setters if your variables are final ?? please illustrate an example where the variables are final and you can change them using setters ?

Comment: @Andrew Where in your question do you mention the variables are `final`? Also, if the variables are `final` - **how** will you change them? The onus is on you (it's your question). `final` fields are set once (in the constructor). That is the only time they can be set.

Comment: To answer your second point, we can set `final` variables in the constructor (unless we've already set them) because the JLS says we can.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch It is well known that the fields are declared as final in the immutable pattern. However all the textbooks , always mention that you myst ensure that the variables are final and you also must ensure that no other methods that change the state of the variables exists.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Thank you very much for your reply. So this means that if our variables are final we will ensure that there will never be  loopholes to change their states ??

Comment: final only means that the variable will always point to the same object. If that object is mutable then a method would be able to change it (eg. a final variable with type `List`).

Comment: @dunes please illustrate this with a code example

Answer (score 0):

The two points are more or less saying the same thing. They just mean, that once the object has been initialised then it should not be changed.

For an object to be truly immutable then every object is references must also not be able to be modified by accessor methods. For instance, the `String` class is backed by a `char[]`, which is mutable. However, the `String` class doesn't expose any methods that let you change the contents of its backing array. Thus, the `String` class can be considered immutable.

With regards to final variables -- variables have to be able to be set somewhere. It wouldn't be a lot of use having a final variable that you were unable set at all. So the constructor is special-cased and allowed to set variables marked as final.

```
class StringArrayList {

    // make the variable private, to protect it from being modified from outside the class
    private final String[] arr;

    StringArrayList(int size) {
        // constructors are the only method allowed to set final variables
        arr = new String[size];
    }

    String get(int i) {
        // get method doesn't change the state of the object, so is fine
        // However, if the object returned is mutable then there might be issues.
        return arr[i];
    }

    void set(int i, String item) {
        // set changes the state of arr, and so with this method, StringArrayList cannot 
        // be considered immutable
        arr[i] = item;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much . One more question , in your code we will get an error while trying to set the arr[i ]= item , since  array arr is final , is that right ?

Comment: No. `arr[i] = item` will work just fine. But, `arr = new String[1]` will result in an error. In the former the object pointed to by `arr` is being mutated. In the latter, the object that arr points to is being changed.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is **defensive copying**. This technique is from "[Effective Java](https://books.google.com.ua/books/about/Effective_Java.html?id=piOyzYqeZGgC&source=kp_book_description&redir_esc=y)" by Joshua Bloch. It's well-known enough so you can read about it either [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=defensive%20copying) or [elsewhere](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22defensive%20copying%22).